# FFmpeg - How to trim with high precision?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am pretty stucked with the way that FFmpeg trims videos, so I would be really grateful if someone could help me. 
Basically, what I am trying to do is: I have a video sequence and I want it to stop in a certain second, freeze the image some seconds (like a pause), and then reproduce again from the same exact frame. I could say that I am dealing with three videos: **A.mp4** (first part of the video sequence), B.mp4 (frozen image) and **C.mp4** (second part of the video sequence). Besides, I also perform an overlay with filter_complex.

The part of generating a video from a static image is not a problem, my main concern is to find the way to trim and concatenate videos accurately. From other posts and sources, I discovered that FFmpeg trims from those Frames that are Keyframes, which can be forced. However, the result I obtain is not the appropriate one, because my video **A** ends in a frame different from the one in the beginning of **C**.

The commands I am using are the following ones:

```
ffmpeg -y -i VideoSequence.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-force_key_frames "expr: gte(t,n_forced * 15)" -t 30 VideoOut.mp4
```

[Note that everything inside Filter Complex is about an Overlay, which works fine]

As far as I know, the resulting video should have a Keyframe every 15 seconds. Now, I want to cut the video into 2 parts ("before second 15" and "after second 15"):

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:01 -i VideoOut.mp4 -t 14 -c copy A.mp4

ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:15 -i VideoOut.mp4 -t 5 -c copy C.mp4
```

As mentioned, I expect the end of A.mp4 to "match" with the beginning of C.mp4 (at a frame precision), but the result I obtain is far from being perfect.

Thank you very much, any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is this the real ffmpeg or the Debian wrapper for libav-tools, and what version?

Comment: Can you also remove anything not relevant to the problem, such as the `-filter_complex`, to give a [mcve].

Comment: @OrangeDog edited. Thanks for the advice. Btw, it is the reall ffmpeg version N-81696-gd38dff8e.

Comment: No, that's the HEAD of the git repo of when it was built. This isn't an official release version then? Do you know what it's closest to without me having to go search release histories?

Comment: Do you understand how MPEG works? A keyframe is a full frame, and it interpolates between keyframes. So if we want to cut at a frame that is not a keyframe, we must generate the frame using the decoder, then insert it as an artificial keyframe.

Comment: @OrangeDog it is an official build version downloaded from Zeranoe (https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) about a month ago. When I ask for "ffmpeg -version", it only returns the version I wrote previously, nothing else. Thanks.

Comment: I wish Zeranoe would set the actual version numbers... I'll assume it's the latest version then.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your end goal is *I want it to stop in a certain second, freeze the image some seconds (like a pause), and then reproduce again from the same exact frame.*, the current method, with multiple video generations, is needlessly wasteful.

Here's the way to do it in one command, assuming the video is 25 FPS.

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -filter_complex
       "[0]split[a][b];
        [a]trim=1:15,loop=75:1:349,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[pre];
        [b]trim=15,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[post];
        [0]atrim=1:15,asetpts=N/SR/TB[apre];
        [0]atrim=15,asetpts=N/SR/TB[apost];
        [pre][apre][post][apost]concat=a=1[v][a]"
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" paused.mp4
```

Here's what is happening in the filtergraph:

First, the video is split to two identical streams. Then the first stream is trimmed from start of 2nd to end of 15th second. In the loop filter, `1` frame starting at (the last frame) #`349` is looped for 75 frames. Then the timestamps are regularized since the trim or loop filters won't do so. The 2nd split stream is trimmed to start from the 16th second, its timestamps reset and the two streams joint using concat. If you need to overlay something on top of the joint stream, insert an `overlay` filter after the concat.

Comment: I have another question: what would you do if, instead of pausing a frame, you want to show another image (i.e. the same one but with some lines and colors)? Thanks!

Comment: After the concat, add the overlay filter to overlay the new image on top of the paused portion by using `enable='between(t,14,17)'`

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't got a framerate defined, I think the problem might be your keyframes not being inserted exactly where you want them. Instead of forcing one every 15 frames, just insert the two that you need:

```
-force_key_frames 00:00:01,00:00:15
```

Or if you only care that the split is clean rather than exactly where the split falls, you can use the segment muxer:

```
-f segment -segment_time 14 out%03d.mp4
```

---

Another idea regarding this [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> -ss *position (input/output)* 
>   When used as an input option (before `-i`), seeks in this input file to position. Note that in most formats it is not possible to seek exactly, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before *position*. When transcoding and `-accurate_seek` is enabled (the default), this extra segment between the seek point and position will be decoded and discarded. When doing stream copy or when `-noaccurate_seek` is used, it will be preserved.
>
> When used as an output option (before an output filename), decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position.

So moving the `-ss` shouldn't make any difference but it's worth a try, especially for older versions that didn't have accurate seeking.

Comment: Thanks for your time @OrangeDog. However, it doesn't seem to work: the first trim is performed properly, but the beginning of the second part overlaps with the end of the first one (both audio and video). I've tried placing -ss before and after -i, but in both cases, the result is incorrect.

Comment: As I said, I don't think -ss will make a difference, but where the keyframes fall.

Comment: What about the other two ideas?

Comment: The one about -force_key_frames is not working. The second one with -segment works pretty well! However, as @Mulvya pointed out in his answer, it is more intelligent not to generate intermediate files and do everything inside filter_complex. Anyway, thank you very much