# Insert frame in video at specific position with ffmpeg

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, video-processing

I’m trying to hold a specific frame of my video for a number of seconds and then resume the video again with ffmpeg.
For example let’s say that I have a video “movie.mp4” and I want to hold the frame at second 10 for 20 seconds. So I want ffmpeg to create a video that looks like:
**10 first seconds of movie.mp4 -> 20 seconds of the frame -> the rest of movie.mp4**

In resume, I want to insert a frame in the video.
My video has audio, that’s one of the things that’s giving me a headache.
Any idea on how to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: See method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981185/5726027).

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly